# Python Pandas GroupBy and Size - Read Values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Sorry all I'm new to this. Hopefully my question is ok.
I'm trying to use pandas to work with the output of a SQL query.
This is my code:

```
data = pandas.read_sql(sql_query, cnxn)

alarmcount = data.groupby(['Module', 'Attribute']).size()
print(alarmcount)
```

The print statement shows the following, which is perfect and exactly what I want.

```
Module      Attribute
TEST_ALM    ALARM1       23
            ALARM2        9
TEST_ALM_1  ALARM1       17
TEST_ALM_2  ALARM1       13
```

But, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to read the data of all three of these columns into my code as strings and integers so I can further process them as required?

I've been at it for a while and have partial success.
The two print statements below:

```
print(alarmcount.tolist())
print(type(alarmcount))
```

The tolist() function returns the last column which is great, but I still cannot access the data from the first two columns as strings.

```
[23, 9, 17, 13]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `groupby.size` output is `Series with MultiIndex`.

One idea is create `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and select by columns:

```
 df = data.groupby(['Module', 'Attribute']).size().reset_index(name='vals')

 print (df['Vals'].tolist())
 print (df['Module'].tolist())
```

Or if need select level in `MultiIndex` use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
alarmcount = data.groupby(['Module', 'Attribute']).size()

print(alarmcount.index.get_level_values('Module').tolist())
```

Comment: perfect thank you